# autotools, stdc++fs, false positive

Tags: c++, c++17, autotools

I am trying to conditionally use std::filesystem if it's available.
Check for header file works, via AM_CHECK_HEADERS first, then AC_TRY_COMPILE (the latter due to some combinations of Xcode/OSX having the header, but firing static assert on actual acompilatilon). Should all those checks pass, HAVE_FILESYSTEM is set.
However the code needs also to be compatible with gcc 7.5.0, which requires linking against libstdc++fs.
Thus, I have added extra check:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([if std::filesystem requires linking stdc++fs])
AC_TRY_LINK([
#if HAVE_FILESYSTEM
#include <filesystem>
#endif
],
[
    std::filesystem::directory_iterator {};
],
    ac_cv_link_fs_stdlib=no,
    ac_cv_link_fs_stdlib=yes)
if test "x$ac_cv_fs_stdlib" = xyes -a "x$ac_cv_class_fs_path" = xyes; then
    AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)
    SYSLIBS="$SYSLIBS -lstdc++fs"
else
    AC_MSG_RESULT(no)
fi
```

Yet it keeps giving me false-positives, i.e. on GCC 7.5.0 gives the answer "no". However the build itself gives this kind of errors:
`utils.cc:(.text+0x2c9b): undefined reference to    std::filesystem::create_directory(std::filesystem::__cxx11::path const&, std::error_code&)`.
Clearly, this looks like linker error to me. How can this be fixed/what is wrong with my configure.ac?
EDITED: tried also with `std::filesystem::path`, `std::filesystem::access` and according to the answer below `std::filesystem::create_directory`. None of those had helped so far. Is it possible to actually see the compiler invocation? Will `set -x` inside configure script do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test only declares a variable that is not being used. Therefore, the test program is not calling any function from `std::filesystem`, thus it will always pass the linking stage. You are also using `AC_TRY_LINK`, which is an obsolete macro, prefer using `AC_LINK_IFELSE` instead. Last, it seems like the variable you set in the `AC_TRY_LINK` statement is different from the one you check: `ac_cv_link_fs_stdlib` is not the same as `ac_cv_fs_stdlib`.

Here is what it should look like:

```
AC_LINK_IFELSE(
    [AC_LANG_SOURCE([
        #if HAVE_FILESYSTEM
        #include <filesystem>
        #endif

        int main() {
            std::error_code ec;
            std::filesystem::create_directory("/dev/null", &ec);
        }
    ])],
    [ac_cv_fs_stdlib=no],
    [ac_cv_fs_stdlib=yes]
)
```

Also be sure to use `AC_PROG_CXX` and set `AC_LANG(C++)` before running this test, if you haven't already.

Comment: I've edited my question, in short: I have tried it before with different functions/objects, no luck either.

Comment: @alagner I updated the answer. I think the real issue is the `ac_...` variable names used.

Comment: Oh gosh, I must have been blind with those variable names, shame on me. Thanks. I will check that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me following solution worked:

```
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX([17], [noext], [mandatory])

AC_LANG_SAVE
 AC_LANG([C++])
# In older versions of gcc implementation of std::filesystem is kept
# in separate stdc++fs library. You should link it explicitly
AC_MSG_CHECKING([if std::filesystem requires linking stdc++fs])
AC_LINK_IFELSE(
    [AC_LANG_SOURCE([
        #include <filesystem>
        int main() {
            std::filesystem::create_directory("/dev/null");
        }
    ])],
    [ac_cv_fs_stdlib=no],
    [ac_cv_fs_stdlib=yes]
)
if test "x$ac_cv_fs_stdlib" = xyes; then
    AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)
    SYSLIBS="$SYSLIBS -lstdc++fs"
else
    AC_MSG_RESULT(no)
fi
AC_LANG_RESTORE
```

Make sure, you use it after turning on C++17 for g++:

```
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX([17], [noext], [mandatory])
```

or something like that. Otherwise this check will always fail, as it will not build without `-std=c++17` option